# Very simple search + date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, date-range

i want to create simple search with date_select fild

forexample i have posts ( title, text and create_at(default) )

and in create_at fild i have something like that: 25/12/2012(in output)

and i want have fild for search in title and text ( i do that ), and fild for date_range (start and end date_fild)

if i put something in this fild i have search like that:

```
named_scope :between, lambda { |starts, ends| { :conditions => ['created_at > ? AND created_at <= ?', starts, ends] } }
```

in simple search i have this:

```
  <%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get', :id => "posts_search" do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>

    <div id="someid"><%= render 'table' %></div>
  <% end %>
```

and this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])
end
```